# Android emulator database file synchronization with Database file?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

i have sqlite database in emulator in data \ ...packagename... \databases\feed.sqlite

whenever my emulator connect with internet at that time my emulator datbase sync with server database.hows it possible ..

**please help me **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take a look at datadroid http://datadroid.foxykeep.com/ It does server synchronization based on RESTful services

Comment: Using RESTful service can synchronization of emulator databse to server database?

Comment: take a look at the google io presentation on the front page of datadroid, it explains everything

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite DB is not that much powerful to do autosync with server. You can achieve this programatically.

link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Comment: can you have any tutorial or example link?